# Edit issue of Joomla's articles in terminal

Tags: joomla

How can you edit Joomla's articles in terminal?

**Problem:** to know the location where Joomla stores its articles

I tried to find articles unsuccessfully by

```
locate Masi | xargs -0 grep great
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The articles are stored in the database in a table called `jos_content`. If you wanted to do a find and replace across them all, open a connection to the database (or use something like phpMyAdmin) and run something like this:

```
 UPDATE `jos_content`
 SET    `introtext` = REPLACE(`introtext`, 'great', 'awesome'),
        `fulltext`  = REPLACE(`fulltext`, 'great', 'awesome')
```

**Edit** to help you debug the problem:
You won't be able to find "jos_content" in your codebase, because of a feature of Joomla which allows you to specify different table prefixes: "jos" is the default prefix. In the code, it's always written like this: `#__content`, and the DBO object converts that to "`jos_content`" behind the scenes.

However, you don't need to be looking in your code at all, just the database. You should be able to connect to the database - all the details you need will be in your `configuration.php` file.

- If you're using Joomla 1.5, the variables you need are called `$host`, `$user`, `$password` and `$db`.
- In Joomla 1.0, the variables are named `$mosConfig_host`, `$mosConfig_user`, `$mosConfig_password` and `$mosConfig_db`

There are a number of ways that you can connect to the database (check with your hosting company if you have phpMyAdmin available: it's quite easy to use), but to do it from the terminal (substitute in your own variables from above):

```
$ mysql -h $host -u $user -p$password -D $db
```

note that there's no space between the -p and the password. From there you should be able to run your own SQL, but I would **highly** recommend making a backup before you do any manual changes.

Comment: I tried to find the string jos_content in my server unsuccessfully by $ find jos_content | xargs grep -L jos .

Comment: It seems that find cannot see inside the database.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla stores articles in a MySQL database. If you want to read/modify/delete articles you'll have to use SQL queries.

If you're determined to do this from a terminal, you could always start the mysql client from the command line and execute your queries from there.

Comment: How can I start a MySQL client in terminal? I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or something you want to do regularly. If you are doing it regularly  would write a quick CLI application on the Joomla platform. Then you can just run it when you need to or make it a cron job.